# Cannot build for WebGL in Unity "Unable to load shared library 'libproc'"

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, .net-core, macos-monterey

MacOS 12.3

Unity 2020.3.31f1

Unity Hub 3.1.1

[Screenshot of error message](https://prnt.sc/mJJt-dMIpBlP)

After updating to MacOS 12.3 I always got this error.
I made unity build before MacOS update without any issues.

Anyone got any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: Please validate the answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Apple removed Python 2 when releasing macOS 12.3 this could be caused by on of the libraries you use or some of its dependencies.

If you use Firebase use this solution https://github.com/techyworm10/firebase-unity-sdk-editor-python-fix

According to Unity they are working on the fix

> Thank you for reporting this issue. We are investigating the issue with building on macOS 12.3.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/cannot-build-for-webgl-in-unity-system-dllnotfoundexception.1254429/